# What is the process of flashing UBI format images on nand flash for openbmc? Do we need to chroot and unmount the file system during flashing?

Tags: openbmc

> ! Recently I study the openbmc ,I am porting openbmc for my development board which is not specialized for BMC functions. The board uses nand flash and I want use the UBI format image on it.But when I study the mechanism of flashing UBI image about openbmc , I found it seems doesn't need to chroot and umount rootfs when flashing the image in running system?
> I copy the xxx.ubi.mtd.tar to /tmp/images/ and activate the flash process by dbus interface,it show the message like this
> [it updatevol ubi0_0 failed, ubi0_0 mounted in "/",In my understanding, it should chroot and the umount the root file system then flash the ubi volume.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F5l8.png)

can anyone tell me the process of flashing UBI Image? I'm new to openbmc,Thanks!